# Other than "/r/n" are there any other escape sequences being pasted when I copy rows from Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, xamdatagrid

I'm currently working on a project that involves copying multiple rows of Excel and pasting them into a single column of a data grid.

Part of the pasting procedure involves firing an event for the paste and programmatically replacing invalid values in the clipboard with valid ones. However, for some reason, the error detection in the data grid is still firing on the valid value being used to replace the bad one.

Example:

```
String temp = Clipboard.GetText();
String[] rows = clipContents.Split(new String[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

String output = "";
foreach(String row in rows)
{
   if(someCollection.Contains(row))
       output += row + "\r\n"     //"VALID_THING" and passes
   else
       output += "VALID_THING" + "\r\n"    //Still getting caught as an error
}

Clipboard.SetText(output);
```

I know the paste event and the modifications fire before the error detection because I can wipe the clipboard clean in the event of a bad value and not have any error detected from the paste.

Comment: No idea if this will help, but you could try replacing the "\r\n" with `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: What do you mean "Still getting caught as an error"? What is `Valid`? What's in the clipboard when your problem occurs? What's the value of `temp`?

Comment: Hi Michael, Valid is just a collection with the allowable values. (Now edited for clarity) A paste error is throw by the XamDataGrid if a pasted string violates the value constraint of the grid. I'm trying to replace the invalid value in the clipboard before the paste occurs. The clipboard appears to show the copy(Temp) as value\r\nvalue\r\n so I'm trying to simulate that with a replacement value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Notepad++ (with the setting view>show symbol>show all characters)to view what is being copied and confirm, but when I copy multiple rows from Excel, the only other characters aside from the carriage return/line feed you mention are tab characters(\t).